# Problem with capturing data from serial via jupyter notebook

Tags: python, arduino, jupyter-notebook, pyserial

This is my arduino code

I closed my arduino ide while running the python code, learned from past mistakes that the com port can only be accessed by one application at a time

```
int analogPin = A0;
int ledPin = 13;
int val = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int ledPin = 13;  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if( millis() % 20 != 0 )       // so a reading is taken every 2 milliseconds
       return;
  // turn the ledPin on
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  val = analogRead(analogPin);  // read the input pin
  Serial.println(val);          // debug value
  // turn the ledPin off:
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```

it works correctly and give me readings every fixed interval
and could be graphed or viewed in the arduino ide integrated serial monitor

This is my python code

```
import time
import logging
import threading
import numpy as np
import cv2
import serial

# configure serial for reading from arduino
# set baudrate and port name accordingly
COM = 'COM6'
baudRate = 9600
sensorDataFileName = r"C:\Users\cy316\Documents\FYP\SensorData.txt"
videoCaptureName = "CameraCapture.mp4"
captureTime = 10
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')

ser = serial.Serial(COM, baudRate)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 for video camera
time.sleep(10) #allow time for arduino to reset
```

```
# function for writing the arduino readings into a file
def sensorreading(ser, stoptime):
    sensordatafile = open(sensorDataFileName,"w+") 
    starttime = time.time()
    data = []

    while ((starttime-time.time())%0.02 == 0): # run every 20ms, better than delay which might or might not be on time
        b = ser.readline()
        string_n = b.decode()
        string = string_n.rstrip()
        flt = float(string)
        print(flt)
        data.append(flt)           # add to the end of data list
        time.sleep(0.02)           # wait for arduino to take new reading

        if (starttime-time.time()>stoptime): # if i reach stoptime, return
            sensordatafile.close()
            return
```

```
# function for video capture
def videocapture(cap, stoptime):
    starttime = time.time()
    # check if camera is available
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("Unable to read camera feed")
        return
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(videoCaptureName,fourcc, 30, (frame_height,frame_width))
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
    while(starttime-time.time()<stoptime):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        out.write(frame)
    out.release()
    return
```

```
# testcell
sensorreading(ser,captureTime)
```

returned only one value, once, and not my specified timing
also failed to write it into the txt file

```
# The cell i want to run for simultaneous sensor and camera values
SensorThread = threading.Thread(target=sensorreading(ser,captureTime), args=(1,))
VideoThread = threading.Thread(videocapture(cap,captureTime), args=(1,))

SensorThread.start()
VideoThread.start()
```

is it because i am running this off jupyter notebook and not something like pycharm?

or is it something to do with the serial code i am missing

Comment: It's difficult to say just looking at your code and not being able to replicate the actual problem. I doubt Jupyter would be causing your issue but you should try running the code as a standalone script to make sure. Try increasing your sleep time to wait for the Arduino serial in Python. Finally, video is obviously very intensive to process, and I'm wondering if there isn't some kind of issue arising from this.

Comment: I have a similar issue, only in my case, Arduino does not respond at all. But when I am using  Arduino IDE no problems. (working in Virtual Box: Linux. scripting in Jupyter Notebook) Chen Yue, did you solve your problem?